# Factor and Inf/NaN

Tags: r, nan, na

I have written a function which converts Inf/NaN values in R to NA. The function goes as follows:

```
DSanity.replaceInfNan <- function(l)
{
     l <- ifelse((is.infinite(l))|(is.nan(l)), NA, l);
     return(l)
}
```

However, when class(l) is a factor, this function returns an object of class integer. Any solutions to get the same class without explicitly checking for class factor? An example is given below.

```
dput(m)    
structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
    22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
    12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
    25L, 26L, 27L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L), .Label = c("1984", "1985", "1986", "1987", "1988", "1989", 
    "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", 
    "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", 
    "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013"
    ), class = "factor")

class(DSanity.replaceInfNan(m))  
"integer"
```

Comment: If your function is designed only for factors, you may operate on levels/labels instead. If not, explicit check seems to be needed. What's so bad about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DSanity.replaceInfNan <- function(l) { 
  l[is.infinite(l) | is.nan(l)] <- NA 
  return(l)
}
```

Comment: can you please explain me why one functions returns integer, while the other returns a factor, even though both the functions are seemingly equivalent? Thanks.

Comment: There's a warning in the help page for `ifelse` stating that _The mode of the result may depend on the value of 'test'_, which is the first parameter to your `ifelse` call.  Even though the third parameter is clearly a factor, the first isn't, and that is what R is using to determine the mode of the return